# Java 8 streams do something with an element which has a boolean field

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I wanna make streams from a list, and do something with an object if an certain field is true.

Let me show you what have I done till now:

```
    List<UserData> userDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    phoneNumbers.forEach(phoneNumber -> {
        if (phoneNumber.getPrimary()) {
            UserData userData = new UserData();
            userData.setDescription(phoneNumber.getType());
            userData.setValue(phoneNumber.getNumber);
            userDataList.add(userData);
        }
    });
```

So if `phoneNumber.getPrimary() == true` will do the following task, if not -
 ignore it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can combine `filter` with `map` to transform the `List` of relevant elements into a `Stream` of `UserData`, and then collect them into a `List`:

```
List<UserData> userDataList =
    phoneNumbers.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getPrimary()) // or filter(ClassName::getPrimary)
                .map(p -> {
                         UserData userData = new UserData();
                         userData.setDescription(p.getType());
                         userData.setValue(p.getNumber());
                         return userData;
                         })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if `UserData` has a constructor that takes the type and number, you can make the code shorter:

```
List<UserData> userDataList =
    phoneNumbers.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getPrimary()) // or filter(ClassName::getPrimary)
                .map(p -> new UserData(p.getType(),p.getNumber()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. But if there is only one object with getPrimary() == true, can I get it directly without put it in a List of objects ?

Comment: @FlorinLei yes, replace `collect` with `findFirst()`.

Comment: @Eran `findAny()` should be preffered when the exact order isn't important

Answer (score 4):

There is already answer Accepted . but I am going to add alternative solution with one line code;

```
 List<UserData> userDataList = phoneNumberList.stream().filter(PhoneNumber::isPrimary)
    .map(UserData::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Let's say Your phone number class have few variables;

```
    public class PhoneNumber {

        private String type;
        private String number;
        private boolean isPrimary;

        public PhoneNumber(String type, String number,boolean isPrimary) {
            this.isPrimary = isPrimary;
            this.type = type;
            this.number = number;
        }

//     getter setters
    }
```

Add Your `UserData` I have added constructor with `Phonenumber` class.which will make easy of adding your data . since i'm going to use  (::) Method Reference.

```
    public class UserData {
        private String description;
        private String value;

        public UserData() {
        }
       //Constructor with PhoneNumber class 
        public UserData(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
            this.description = phoneNumber.getType();
            this.value = phoneNumber.getNumber();
        }
// getter setter
     }
```

So let say have a list of `phonenumers` itearaion with one line.

```
        List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList = new ArrayList<>();
                phoneNumberList.add(new PhoneNumber("Landline","40054638",false));
                phoneNumberList.add(new PhoneNumber("Work","90054638",true));
                phoneNumberList.add(new PhoneNumber("Office","7891432654",false));
                phoneNumberList.add(new PhoneNumber("Personal","40054638",true));
        //PhoneNumber::isPrimary this will check only primary 
//UserData::new will set values Phonenumber to UserData 
                List<UserData> userDataList = phoneNumberList.stream().filter(PhoneNumber::isPrimary)
    .map(UserData::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

                System.out.println(userDataList);
                System.out.println(userDataList.size());
```